Multiplication of convergent sequence and multiplication of series
It is a basic rule that 
$((\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n}=A\in\mathbb{R})\wedge (lim_{n\to \infty }b_{n}=B\in\mathbb{R})\Rightarrow lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n}b_{n})=AB)$
And according to the definition of series:
Let $(x_{k})$be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, $s_{n}:=\sum_{k=0}^{n}x_{k}$,then the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x_{k}$ is convergent if $\lim_{n\to \infty}s_{n}\in \mathbb{R}$.That is $(s_{n})$ is convergent.
My question is that：
Let $a_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}x_{k}, b_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}y_{k}$
$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x_{k}=A,\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}y_{k}=B$
According to the multiplication of convergent sequence and the series are special sequences,
is
$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n}b_{n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}\lim_{n\to\infty }b_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x_{k}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}y_{k}=AB$ establish?

The answer to this question seems to be incorrect. The discussion of the multiplication of series unfolded in a complex way. Because the multiplication of infinte sum is different from finite. But I can't find the limitations of multiplication of convergence sequence.
In this question，if we define $c_{n}$ as follows $\sum_{k=0}^{n}x_{k}\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n}y_{k}=\sum_{0\le k,j\le n}x_{k}y_{j}=:c_{n}$, is this definition acceptable?

Am I missing something? Thank you for your help!

The product of two convergent sequences (in this case $a_n$ and $b_n$) is indeed convergent and is equal to the product of the limits. The way you have written it just makes it a bit less clear, but in essence we have a $a_n \to A$ and $b_n \to B$, so we definitely also have $a_nb_n \to AB$
